ENVI band math map variable not including all bands
I am using a band math equation in envi that applies to to all 8 bands of an image. However, when I use map variable to input file, only six bands are selected. The file in the data manager also shows errors for these bands (NIR). This error happens on images that I used Flaash atmospheric correction on, and not on the original images. Can someone help address thi issue?
